# How to login in case request is redirected

Tags: node.js, http, http-post, puppeteer

I have this basic post request:

```
 'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const request_client = require('request-promise-native');

(async () => {

  // Create browser instance, and give it a first tab
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    // Allows you to intercept a request; must appear before
    // your first page.goto()
    await page.setRequestInterception(true);

    // Request intercept handler... will be triggered with 
    // each page.goto() statement
    page.on('request', interceptedRequest => {

        // Here, is where you change the request method and 
        // add your post data
        var data = {
            'method': 'POST',
            'postData': 'HasSell=true&ModelYears=2005&MaxModelYearHidden=2020&Brands=BMW&ModelNames=SERIES+3&TransmissionTypes=Otomatik&FuelTypes=Dizel&CarCases=Sedan&Versions=320D+AUTO&HorsePowers=150&MaxHorsePowerHidden=163&IsDontKnowHorsePowerHidden=0&Km=5.000&IsDontKnowKmHidden=0&OuterDemage-1=1-1&OuterDemage-2=2-1&OuterDemage-3=3-1&OuterDemage-4=4-1&OuterDemage-5=5-1&OuterDemage-6=6-1&OuterDemage-7=7-1&OuterDemage-8=8-1&OuterDemage-9=9-1&OuterDemage-10=10-1&OuterDemage-11=11-1&EquipmentCheckBoxSIS+FARI=SIS+FARI&EquipmentCheckBoxSUNROOF=SUNROOF&EquipmentCheckBoxYOL+BILGISAYARI=YOL+BILGISAYARI&progressValue=10',
            headers: {

            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
          }
       };

        // Request modified... finish sending! 
        interceptedRequest.continue(data);
    });

    // Navigate, trigger the intercept, and resolve the response
    const response = await page.goto('https://www.ikinciyeni.com/fiyatlandirici');     
    const responseBody = await response.text();
    console.log(responseBody);

    // Close the browser - done! 
    //await browser.close();

    })();
```

In the code above, I have given the url to which the post request is sent. It gets redirected and eventually lands on login page. How do I login in this case? How are the login credentials given?

Edit:
I have added this code in the end:

```
// Navigate, trigger the intercept, and resolve the response
    const response = await page.goto('https://www.ikinciyeni.com/fiyatlandirici'); 
    await page.waitForNavigation({
      waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
    });
    await page.type('#EmailRetail', 'scott');
    await page.type('#Password', 'tiger');

    await page.click('#LoginSubmitBtn');
    await page.waitForNavigation();
    const responseBody = await response.text();
    console.log(responseBody);
```

But it throws this exception:

```
 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded
    at E:\code\generic_scrapper\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\LifecycleWatcher.js:100:111
    at async FrameManager.waitForFrameNavigation (E:\code\generic_scrapper\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\FrameManager.js:107:23)
    at async Frame.waitForNavigation (E:\code\generic_scrapper\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\FrameManager.js:298:16)
    at async Page.waitForNavigation (E:\code\generic_scrapper\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:492:16)
    at async E:\code\generic_scrapper\post.js:39:2
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame.<anonymous> (E:\code\generic_scrapper\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:94:19)
    at Page.waitForNavigation (E:\code\generic_scrapper\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:492:53)
    at Page.<anonymous> (E:\code\generic_scrapper\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:95:27)
    at E:\code\generic_scrapper\post.js:39:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:11400) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11400) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
^C
E:\code\generic_scrapper>node post.js
(node:18352) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded
    at E:\code\generic_scrapper\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\LifecycleWatcher.js:100:111
    at async FrameManager.waitForFrameNavigation (E:\code\generic_scrapper\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\FrameManager.js:107:23)
    at async Frame.waitForNavigation (E:\code\generic_scrapper\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\FrameManager.js:298:16)
    at async Page.waitForNavigation (E:\code\generic_scrapper\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:492:16)
    at async E:\code\generic_scrapper\post.js:39:2
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame.<anonymous> (E:\code\generic_scrapper\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:94:19)
    at Page.waitForNavigation (E:\code\generic_scrapper\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:492:53)
    at Page.<anonymous> (E:\code\generic_scrapper\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:95:27)
    at E:\code\generic_scrapper\post.js:39:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:18352) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:18352) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
^C
E:\code\generic_scrapper>node post.js
(node:11528) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded
    at E:\code\generic_scrapper\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\LifecycleWatcher.js:100:111
    at async FrameManager.waitForFrameNavigation (E:\code\generic_scrapper\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\FrameManager.js:107:23)
    at async Frame.waitForNavigation (E:\code\generic_scrapper\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\FrameManager.js:298:16)
    at async Page.waitForNavigation (E:\code\generic_scrapper\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:492:16)
    at async E:\code\generic_scrapper\post.js:39:2
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame.<anonymous> (E:\code\generic_scrapper\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:94:19)
    at Page.waitForNavigation (E:\code\generic_scrapper\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:492:53)
    at Page.<anonymous> (E:\code\generic_scrapper\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:95:27)
    at E:\code\generic_scrapper\post.js:39:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:11528) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11528) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

How do I fix this issue? My intuition was to wait until page is loaded and then click and enter information.

Edit1:

I removed waitForNavigation() and this is the exception that Im getting

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Protocol error (Network.getResponseBody): No resource with given identifier found
    at E:\code\generic_scrapper\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Connection.js:152:63
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at CDPSession.send (E:\code\generic_scrapper\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Connection.js:151:16)
    at E:\code\generic_scrapper\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\HTTPResponse.js:58:53
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async HTTPResponse.text (E:\code\generic_scrapper\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\HTTPResponse.js:67:25)
    at async E:\code\generic_scrapper\post.js:45:26
  -- ASYNC --
    at HTTPResponse.<anonymous> (E:\code\generic_scrapper\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:94:19)
    at E:\code\generic_scrapper\post.js:45:41
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:15292) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:15292) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Edit2:
With or without credentials it lands to this page : https://www.ikinciyeni.com/giris However, it should land to such a page: https://www.ikinciyeni.com/konsinye-hesap-sonuc?tempId=....

What could be the reason behind this? Could it be because it doesn't have credentials sent to it?

Edit3:
This is what request looks like from website(Chrome)

```
POST https://www.ikinciyeni.com/giris HTTP/1.1
Host: www.ikinciyeni.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 296
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Origin: https://www.ikinciyeni.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Referer: https://www.ikinciyeni.com/giris?ReturnUrl=/konsinye-hesap-sonuc&tempId=2a26816b-62ed-4603-bfec-473342f58de7
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: __gads=ID=b7b47e7d0a959312:T=1
__RequestVerificationToken=Amij.....
```

while this is what it looks like in case of Pupeteer

```
POST https://www.ikinciyeni.com/giris HTTP/1.1
Host: www.ikinciyeni.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 595
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Referer: https://www.ikinciyeni.com/giris?ReturnUrl=/konsinye-hesap-sonuc&tempId=a92c918b-4745-4c79-9cd4-cb31084468b3
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.0 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=mfy3sm5da1b1xdiro52dtqqn; Cookie_DimensionId=477094; NSC_xxx.jljodjzfoj.dpn_iuuqt=ffffffffaf1fc83045525d5f4f58455e445a4a423660; __RequestVerificationToken=-5v7ZraCIzfPQ4ViK6x1oEBjXzzxn9v0HV_q8lkdwCGiOOT9ChF7-N1Ya2tn3D1rbvIRdw1mw_BCPe50aluylMqS5qo1

HasSell=true&ModelYears=2005&MaxModelYearHidden=2020&Brands=BMW&ModelNames=SERIES+3&TransmissionTypes=Otomatik&FuelTypes=Dizel&CarCases=Sedan&Versions=320D+AUTO&HorsePowers=150&MaxHorsePowerHidden=163&IsDontKnowHorsePowerHidden=0&Km=5.000&IsDontKnowKmHidden=0&OuterDemage-1=1-1&OuterDemage-2=2-1&OuterDemage-3=3-1&OuterDemage-4=4-1&OuterDemage-5=5-1&OuterDemage-6=6-1&OuterDemage
```

I need to append my email and password in latter case.

Edit:
Headers generated by browser itself get overriden with the ones I have mentioned in POST. Is there any way I could add these to existing headers rather than overriding them?

Comment: Based on your _Edit_ and _Edit1_ your script doesn't grab correctly the login form, so puppeteer timeouts. Check my solution below with an if condition around the login, it waits for the selectors for me properly. Also the `page.click` + `page.keyboard.type` may works better, but normally they should have the same result in terms of form usage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have valid credentials of their website first. Then you can put a condition in your script: check if you are on the login page, and if you are, then type the credentials via puppeteer like a real user would do. Select the input fields by clicking into them then use the api's `keyboard.type`. (You are able to navigate between input fields with `keyboard.press()` as well.)

Don't forget to store your credentials in environment variables if you'd go this way!

```js
[...]
  await page.goto('https://www.ikinciyeni.com/fiyatlandirici')

  if ((await page.$('#EmailRetail')) !== null) {
    // select and type the email
    await page.click('#EmailRetail')
    await page.keyboard.type('example@example.com')
    // select and type the password
    await page.click('#Password')
    await page.keyboard.type('password0123')
    // submit the form
    await page.click('#LoginSubmitBtn')
  }

  const responseBody = await page.content()
  console.log(responseBody)
[...]
```

Comment: These were just for an example. I have added real login credentials

Comment: Please check my Edit 2